# Pygame majority of the key inputs are not working, eg(w, a, s, d). Only the arrow keys seem to be working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, keydown

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

running = True

x = 50
y = 50

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while running:
    
    clock.tick(60)
    
    screen.fill((0, 255, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), (x, y, 30, 30))
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            x += 5
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            x -= 5    
        if event.key == pygame.K_s:`enter code here`
            y += 5
        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            y -= 5    
        
    pygame.display.update()
```

Trying to move my second sprite with the w, a, s, d, keys, however it does not seem to be working. When I change pygame.K_d to pygame.K_RIGHT, it works well just as normal. Wondering if I've made a mistake in my code or it is an error with my keyboard. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to indent the `if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN` block so it is in the for loop. Otherwise it won't process the events. The reason it works with arrow keys is because the event variable is the last event in the event queue, which for non text input is not masked by TEXTINPUT events after KEYDOWN events.

Comment: Aight got it! Thanks mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). The event needs to be evaluated in the event loop:

```py
while running:
    
    clock.tick(60)
    
    screen.fill((0, 255, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), (x, y, 30, 30))
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # INDENTATION
    #-->|
            
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                x += 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                x -= 5    
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:`enter code here`
                y += 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                y -= 5    
        
    pygame.display.update()
```

However, the keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. The `KEYDOWN` event occurs once every time a key is pressed. `KEYUP` occurs once every time a key is released. Use the keyboard events for a single action or a step-by-step movement.

If you want to achieve a continuously movement, you have to use `pygame.key.get_pressed()`. [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a list with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`. Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button and get continuous movement:

```py
while running:
    
    clock.tick(60)
    
    screen.fill((0, 255, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), (x, y, 30, 30))
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        x += 5
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        x -= 5    
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        y += 5
    if keys[pygame.K_w]
        y -= 5    
        
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Very in depth, thanks a lot!